# ng-click event binding not working inside angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatables for listing student information. I want to implement server-side ajax implementation for every search, sorting, paging etc rather than fetch all data and repeat the data using angularjs. sorting, searching, paging is working fine. But I am unable to bind `ng-click` event when click on specific row actions.

This is my view:
[image: This is my view]

This is my javascript source code:
[image: this is my javascript source code]

```
<div ng-app="myApp"> 
  <div ng-controller="OrganizationController">
    <table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" 
           dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['datatables']);
    app.controller('OrganizationController', BindAngularDirectiveCtrl);
    function BindAngularDirectiveCtrl($scope, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = '';
        vm.edit = edit;
        vm.dtInstance = {};
        vm.persons = {};
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("organization_name").withOption('organization_name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
                    .renderWith(actionsHtml)
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
                    dataSrc: "data",
                    url: "organizations",
                    type:"get"
                })
                .withOption('processing', true) //for show progress bar
                .withOption('serverSide', true) // for server side processing
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers') // for get full pagination options // first / last / prev / next and page numbers
                .withDisplayLength(2) // Page size
                .withOption('aaSorting',[0,'asc'])
        function edit() {
            console.log('hi')
        }

        function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
            vm.persons[data.id] = data;
            return '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit()">' +
                    '   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' +
                    '</button>';
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.  The place where we take your code and try to help....  BUT you must provide code and information to your problem.  Show us what you have tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add `withOption("rowCallback",fn)`

```js
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',['datatables']);
    app.controller('OrganizationController', BindAngularDirectiveCtrl);
    function BindAngularDirectiveCtrl($scope, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.message = '';
        vm.edit = edit;
        vm.dtInstance = {};
        vm.persons = {};
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("organization_name").withOption('organization_name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
                    .renderWith(actionsHtml)
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
                    dataSrc: "data",
                    url: "organizations",
                    type:"get"
                })
                .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
                .withOption('processing', true) //for show progress bar
                .withOption('serverSide', true) // for server side processing
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers') // for get full pagination options // first / last / prev / next and page numbers
                .withDisplayLength(2) // Page size
                .withOption('aaSorting',[0,'asc'])
        function edit() {
            console.log('hi')
        }

        function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
            vm.persons[data.id] = data;
            return '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit()">' +
                    '   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' +
                    '</button>';
        }

      function rowCallback(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
        $('td', nRow).unbind('click');
        $('td', nRow).bind('click', function() 
        {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
               alert("You've clicked row," + iDisplayIndex);
            });
        });
        return nRow;
    }

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to bind a click event to specific DOM element in angular datatable row find(jQuery)that element using any CSS selector. For example -

HTML

```
<table id='table' datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Angular(v4) Component-

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

    ngOnInit() {
        //Starts Angular jQuery DataTable server side processing settings
        let ajaxSettings: any = {
            settings: {
                ajax: {
                    ...
                },
                serverSide: true,
                searchDelay: 800,
                deferRender: true,
                processing: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                stateSave: false,
                searching: true,
                aoColumns: [
                    //Table column definition
                    {
                        //Action Column
                        sTitle: 'Action',
                        sWidth: "20%",
                        bSearchable: false,
                        bSortable: false,
                        mRender: (data, type, full) => {
                            return "<a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='custombtn btn btn-sm btn-primary'><span class='fa fa-paper-plane-o'></span>Action Button</a>";
                        }
                    }
                ],
                fnServerParams: function (data) {

                },
                initComplete: () => {

                },
                rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
                    const self = this;
                    // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler
                    // (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
                    var element = $('td', row).find('a.custombtn');
                    if (element) {
                        element.unbind('click');
                        element.bind('click', () => {
                            self.someClickHandler(data, index);
                        });
                    }
                    return row;
                }
            }
        };

        this.dtOptions = ajaxSettings.settings;
        //Ends Angular jQuery DataTable server side processing settings
    }

//Will be called on click of anchor tag which has the class "custombtn"
    someClickHandler(info: any, index: number): void {
        alert(JSON.stringify(info) + ' index =>' + index);
    }

}
```